# How to pass several $_GET parameters in blade from different anchor tags in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

so far I've passed one get parameter from an anchor tag like this:

`<a class="zone" href="{{route('home', ['zone' => 'europe'])}}">Europe</a>`

How to pass another one if I want to combine them both? If I do: `<a class="time" href="{{route('home', ['time' => 'today'])}}">Today</a>` than the zone parameter will be removed. How to pass both parameters to the same route from the anchor tags in order to have a url like this `https://example.com/?zone=europe&time=today` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many parameters as you want in the array, so if you have to add the zone, just update your code as follows:

```
route('home', ['time' => 'today', 'zone' => 'europe'])
```

Remeber that you can have these parameters both in the route definition

```
Route::get('home/{time}/{zone}', 'YourController@yourMethod');
```

And define your controller as follows:

```
class YourController extends Controller {
   public function yourMethod(Request $request, $time, $zone) {
      dd($time) // 'today';
      dd($zone) // 'europe';
   }
}
```

Or you can simply retrieve them from the request as follows:

```
// Route:
Route::get('home', 'YourController@yourMethod');

// Controller:
class YourController extends Controller {
   public function yourMethod(Request $request) {
      dd($request->time) // 'today';
      dd($request->zone) // 'europe';
   }
}
```

Comment: I know, but how to do this from two different anchor tags? One anchor should pass parameter time and another should pass parameter zone.

Comment: You mean you want to pass first a parameter and on a second click another parameter to the controller?

Comment: Yes I couldn't describe it more accurately. Thank you! This is the goal. Pass one parameter first and on a second click pass the second parameter and not remove the first one.

Comment: It's a little strange what you're trying to do... Anyway, just save it in session and on second click you look for the `time` parameter existance in session, otherwise throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Inside your route definition, pass two parameters:

```
Route::get('/home/{zone}/{time}', 'Controller')
```

After that, pass the both parameters in your view, where you call the route:

```
<a class="time" href="{{route('home', ['time' => 'today', 'zone'=>'europe'])}}">Today</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to do this from two different anchor tags? One anchor should pass parameter time and another should pass parameter zone.